# How to make artificially-intelligent nanobots that 'ride' on blood cells realistic?

Tags: creative-writing

I have a character idea where said character is a gadgeteer/artificer type, and they have these nanobots in their blood stream that they use to make the items they need. The nanobots also have an artificial intelligence that allows them to think on the fly, almost like a human.

Comment: I feel like this would be a better question for [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

### Treat your nano-bots as your story's magic system.

They need rules to govern their operation so they are predictable and constrained in their power.  They need to be predictable so readers can guess how this nano-bots are going to save the day or raise the conflict. It's okay if the reader gets surprised or gets it wrong. Everything that happens needs to be rational given the rules.

If the nano-bots are infinitely powerful then no characters are ever in danger, nor is any struggle ever in doubt because the nano-bots will win. Boring at best and a power fantasy at worst.

### It's the reason Superman versus Bambi is not very exciting.

Things to consider are what powers the nano-bots -- and this part is discussion for worldbuilding@se.

- Do they convert protein and sugars in his blood stream, so the complete with the host for sustenance?
- What senses do they possess?  How do they experience the universe? Sensory stimulation influences perception and communication and worldview.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this isn't too hard to think about, since it very well could be reality soon. Many healthcare companies are working on similar nanobots to, say, seek and destroy cancer cells without the need for dangerous surgery. Here's a link to an article on the subject: [www.therobotreport.com/nanobots-promise-change-medical-treatment](http://www.therobotreport.com/nanobots-promise-change-medical-treatment)